# How to increase and decrease the label value (price) according to Plus Minus button count in swift

Tags: json, swift, button, label

I am getting price from JSON like below and showing in screen, which is working fine

```
func populatePage() {

let detailsData = detailsDB?.result?.product?.product_details
price = detailsData?.price ?? ""
discountPrice = detailsData?.discount_price ?? ""

self.lblDiscountPrice.text = discountPrice != "0.000" && compareDate(fromDate: detailsData?.from_date ?? "", toDate: detailsData?.to_date ?? "") ? "\(discountPrice) KWD" : "\(price) KWD"
self.lblRealPrice.text = discountPrice != "0.000" && compareDate(fromDate: detailsData?.from_date ?? "", toDate: detailsData?.to_date ?? "") ? "\(price) KWD" : ""
self.lblLine.isHidden = discountPrice != "0.000" && compareDate(fromDate: detailsData?.from_date ?? "", toDate: detailsData?.to_date ?? "") ? false : true
 }
```

I need according to increment, decrement count the price also increase and decrease, how?

```
 @IBAction func increment(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.productCount += 1
    
    self.lblProductCount.text = productCount.description
    
}
@IBAction func decrement(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.productCount >= 2 {
        self.productCount -= 1
        self.lblProductCount.text = self.productCount.description
    }
}
```

Please help me do this

Comment: The same way productCount is a property you use for keeping track of the count you need a property of type Double that holds the price. If your json contains a plain number without any formatting you should be able to use `Double(discount_price)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson.. when decrease.. then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this sample code:

```
private var itemQuantity: Int = 1 //By Defaults: 1

@IBAction func onTapDecreaseQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    updateItemQuantity(isIncreasing: false)
}

@IBAction func onTapIncreaseQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    updateItemQuantity(isIncreasing: true)
}

private func updateItemQuantity(isIncreasing: Bool) {
    guard let price = item?.itemPrice else { return }
    itemQuantity = isIncreasing ? itemQuantity + 1: itemQuantity - 1
    itemQuantityLabel.text = String(itemQuantity)
    itemPriceLabel.text = "Price: $\((price * Float(itemQuantity)).toString(fractionDigits: 2))"
    minusItemNumberButton.isEnabled = itemQuantity > 1
}
```

You will need to parse from String to Number by type-casting whether it is double or float number. I am using a local var **Int** type to handle  increment and decrement operators.
To assign the number back to String we could use the following extension:

```
extension Float {
    func toString(fractionDigits: Int) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = fractionDigits
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? "\(self)"
    }
}
```

Hope this help you out.